# Center text in Xamarin Entry

Tags: wpf, xamarin

```
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding QuantityString, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
          <Entry.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:NumericalValidationBehavior Minimum="{Binding MinQuantity}" Maximum="{Binding MaxQuantity}"/>
          </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
```

This is my `Entry` but the text isn't centered. I tried to add multiple alignment parameters.

It seems that I'm obliged to create my own `Entry`, `Renderer`, ... Is there anything more simple than this for just centering a text in Android Xamarin ?

Comment: Did you try to set HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" instead of HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"?

Comment: Why are you running from CustomRenderers?... they are great and very powerful feature. It is like a 5-10 min of work and you can make some great improvements. So I advise you to solve this using custom renderers.

Comment: `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"` did the trick, thanks @MarlonRibeiro.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy. Just set the property `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"` like this:

```
<Entry 
   Text="{Binding Path=LionsValue}" 
   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
```